# predefined or pre-defined?

Tags: word-choice, hyphens

Which of the following is the correct usage of the word, and why?

> The user can use **pre-defined** lists.
>
> The user can use **predefined** lists.

Comment: Did you try looking either one of these up in a dictionary? What did you find?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"New Oxford Dictionary for Writers and Editor" clearly states that "predefined, one word".

Why? I suppose that that pre-word is in common usage today, so there is no need to use the hypen.